# Update MainWindow based on actions in SecondWindow

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy and struggling to change elements in MainWindow based on what happens in SecondWindow. The code below is how far I have got on my own. The clicking of the "A" button in SecondWindow fires an event in WindowManager and prints "A" in console. However, I would like to update id: labeltext in MainWindow based on that click. Can that be done directly somehow or do how do I pass information from WindowManager to MainWindow. If so, how? I am new to object oriented programming so these things cause a lot of head scratching to me. Thank you!

Python code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def keykey(self,whichkey):
        print(whichkey)


kv = Builder.load_file("multiscreen.kv")    
        
class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
      
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Kivy:

```
WindowManager:    
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
   
    
<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    
    labeltext: labeltext 
    
    Label:
        id: labeltext
        text: "XXX"
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.8}    
    
    Button:
        text: "Go Second"
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.9, "y":0.9}        
        on_release: 
            app.root.current = "second"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                        
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    
    Button:
        text: "A"
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "y":0.5}       
        on_release:
            root.manager.keykey('A')
            print("dfd")
        
    Button:
        text: "Go Main"
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.0, "y":0.9}  
        on_release: 
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `kv`, change the rule for the `Button` to include:

```
root.manager.get_screen('main').ids.labeltext.text = 'New Text'
```